# Can Compodoc be installed offline?

Tags: angular, documentation, compodoc

I need to somehow get the files for Compodoc downloaded and moved to another system that does not have internet access.

How can I download the Compodoc utility and install it to the offline system?

I don't see any information pertaining to offline installs on their site.
https://compodoc.app/guides/installation.html

This tool generates documentation for the Angular CLI project and our project really needs to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local npm working folder, and then copy that folder.

```sh
mkdir example
cd example
npm init
npm install --save-dev @compodoc/compodoc
```

This will install compodoc in the `node_modules` and you can run it on an offline machine via `example/node_modules/bin/compodoc`.

It can be made a global command if you add it to the user's path.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you @Reactgular

Comment: will do. Just may take a few days as I have submit a request and wait for SAs to move files over to the system.